# Forgiven because or therefore forgiven in Luke 7:47

Tags: greek, jesus, grammar, forgiveness

Was the woman of Luke 7:47 forgiven because she loved much or did she love much as a result of being forgiven ? What does the grammar of the Greek say ? ( or is the Greek vague and it could go either way ? )

> Therefore I say to you, her sins, which are many, are forgiven, for she loved much.
> But to whom little is forgiven, the same loves little.
> — Luke 7:47 (NKJV)

Answer (score 1):

This question concerns the correct understanding of the final sentence in Luke 7:47 which reads:

> ... ᾧ δὲ ὀλίγον ἀφίεται, ὀλίγον ἀγαπᾷ = But, to whom little is
> forgiven, he love little.

The sense is clear as most modern versions make clear:

- NIV: But whoever has been forgiven little loves little.”
- ESV: But he who is forgiven little, loves little.”
- BLB: but to whom little is forgiven, he loves little."

However, the previous sentence in the same verse: "Her many sins have been forgiven, for she loved much", which is the reverse sense.

That is both sense are provided in the same verse, but this appears unlikely as Ellicott notes:

> (47) Her sins, which are many, are forgiven.—Grammatically, the words
> admit of two interpretations, equally tenable. (1) Love may be
> represented as the ground of forgiveness, existing prior to it, and
> accepted as that which made forgiveness possible; or (2) it may be
> thought of as the natural consequence of the sense of being forgiven,
> and its manifestations as being therefore an evidence of a real and
> completed forgiveness. The whole drift of the previous parable is in
> favour of the latter explanation. The antecedent conditions of
> forgiveness, repentance, and faith—faith in Christ where He has been
> manifested to the soul as such; faith in Him as the Light that
> lighteth every man where He has not so been manifested—must be
> pre-supposed in her case as in others. And the faith was pre-eminently
> one that “worked by love,” from the first moment of its nascent life.
> In such cases we may, if need be, distinguish for the sake of accuracy
> of thought, and say that it is faith and not love that justifies, but
> it is an evil thing to distinguish in order to divide.

Thus, the thrust of Jesus' teaching her appears to be that when one realizes the extent of God's grace and its associated forgiveness, one love much.  That is, we do not love in order to be forgiven - love is NOT a work we do earn forgiveness which is grace alone!

Comment: The NLT makes this more explicit: "*… so she has shown me much love. But a person who is forgiven little shows only little love.*".

Answer (score 1):

The verbs that are rendered as “forgiven” in Lk 7:47 (aphiémi, [Strong’s 863](https://biblehub.com/greek/863.htm)) are in the passive voice, meaning that the forgiveness of sins is the action and prerogative of God alone. Take for example the passive voice in this sentence: “The tables have been covered.” The tables are passive recipients of the action of the verb; the agent of that action is exclusive to another.

In addition, the subject of the verb forgiven is not the woman but her sins.

> Therefore I say to you this: Her many sins have been forgiven, for she
> loved much; but to whom little is forgiven, he loves little. - Berean
> Literal Bible

In other words, God’s forgiveness is independent of any action on the part of the woman - whether passive, active, or middle (voice of [Greek verbs](https://wordofgracestudies.org/pastors-notes/greek-grammar-rescue/koine-greek-verb/)). The grammar is carefully crafted to avoid any ambiguity; God is the sole agent of the forgiveness in Lk 7:47 (cf Rom 9:15-16).

Based on this discussion, the relationship between love and forgiveness is not a causal one. Rather, what Lk 7:47 describes is the proportional and bi-directional correlation between love and forgiveness. That is, the more that one loves, the more that is forgiven. The converse is also true, as is illustrated by the parable in verses 41-42: the more that is forgiven, the greater is the love.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is "because" rather than "therefore".

---

οὖν rather than ὅτι is the conjunction meaning "therefore".  Examples from Luke:

> μὴ ἐχόντων δὲ αὐτῶν ἀποδοῦναι, ἀμφοτέροις ἐχαρίσατο. τίς **οὖν**
> αὐτῶν, εἰπέ, πλεῖον αὐτὸν ἀγαπήσει;
>
> *And when they had nothing with which to repay, he freely forgave them both. Tell Me, **therefore**, which of them will love him more?* (Luke
> 7:42)

> ὁ λύχνος τοῦ σώματός ἐστιν ὁ ὀφθαλμός· ὅταν **οὖν** ὁ ὀφθαλμός σου
> ἁπλοῦς ᾖ, καὶ ὅλον τὸ σῶμά σου φωτεινόν ἐστιν· ἐπὰν δὲ πονηρὸς ᾖ, καὶ
> τὸ σῶμά σου σκοτεινόν.
>
> *The lamp of the body is the eye. **Therefore**, when your eye is good, your whole body also is full of light. But when your eye is bad,
> your body also is full of darkness* (Luke 11:34)

---

An explanation of the verse from a Greek Church Father, Cyril of Alexandria:

> She had much to be forgiven, and so she loved much. For those who have
> been forgiven little, love little. She had committed many sins, and
> therefore was filled with gratitude for the forgiveness that she had
> received. And the Lord, who knows the hearts of all, perceived her
> faith and her repentance, and forgave her sins (*Commentary on Luke*,
> *PG* 72:533ff.

Answer (score 0):

A good article on this issue is found here:

https://www.sil.org/system/files/reapdata/99/91/05/9991051880672198991400822534137118167/siljot2022_1_02.pdf

In short, the greek word used here, ⲟⲧⲓ can be...

- Causal (e.g. her loving caused her forgiveness)
- Evidential (e.g. her loving is *evidence* of her forgiveness)

The better understanding in the context here is the evidential usage of ⲟⲧⲓ.

it's nice to see some newer translations pick up on this nuance:

- “Therefore I tell you, her many sins have been forgiven; that’s why she loved much. But the one who is forgiven little, loves little.”” (Luke 7:47 CSB17)
- “Therefore, I tell you, her many sins have been forgiven—as her great love has shown. But whoever has been forgiven little loves little.”” (Luke 7:47 NIV11-GKE)